# Not able to change button style from follow to unfollow when click on it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

So, I am implementing follow/unfollow features with firebase. I am able to follow and unfollow users by updating it in firebase but not able to change the button style where I make conditions for follow and unfollow.

Here is my following/unfollow user code:

```
``  Future<void> followUser(String targetUserId) async {
    final DocumentReference userDoc =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users_info').doc(_userId);
    final DocumentReference targetUserDoc =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users_info').doc(targetUserId);

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      final userSnapshot = await transaction.get(userDoc);
      final targetUserSnapshot = await transaction.get(targetUserDoc);

      if (!userSnapshot.exists || !targetUserSnapshot.exists) {
        throw Exception('Document does not exist!');
      }

      final Map<String, dynamic> userData = userSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final Map<String, dynamic> targetUserData =
      targetUserSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

      List<String> following = List<String>.from(userData['following']);
      List<String> followers = List<String>.from(targetUserData['followers']);

      if (!following.contains(targetUserId)) {
        following.add(targetUserId);
        userData['followingCount'] = following.length.clamp(0, 1000000);
        targetUserData['followerCount'] = (followers.length + 1).clamp(0, 1000000);
        followers.add(_userId!);
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        following.remove(targetUserId);
        userData['followingCount'] = following.length.clamp(0, 1000000);
        targetUserData['followerCount'] = (followers.length - 1).clamp(0, 1000000);
        followers.remove(_userId);
        notifyListeners();
      }

      if (userData['followingCount'] < 0 || targetUserData['followerCount'] < 0) {
        throw Exception('Invalid follow/unfollow operation!');
      }

      transaction.update(userDoc, {'following': following, 'followingCount': userData['followingCount']});
      transaction.update(targetUserDoc, {'followers': followers, 'followerCount': targetUserData['followerCount']});
    });
  }`
```

Here is ui where i fetch user and than implment follow/unfollow feature on them

`

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users_info')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    final List<UserData> allUsers =
                        snapshot.data!.docs
                    .map((doc) => UserData.fromSnapshot(
                          doc.data(),
                          doc.id
                        )).toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: allUsers.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          UserData user = allUsers[index];
                          bool isCurrentUser = user.uid == allUserProvider.currentUser?.uid;
                         final bool isFollowing =
                         allUserProvider.currentUser?.following?.contains(user.uid ?? '') ?? false;
                        if(user.uid == currentUserId){
                          return Container();
                        }
                          return  ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(user.image ?? ''),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                user.name ?? '',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: GlobalVariables.fontsPally,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                user.uid ?? 'no id',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFFC1C0C9),
                                  fontFamily: GlobalVariables.fontsSatoshi,
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: !isCurrentUser ?
                                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                                    print('${userId} and ${user.uid}');
                                 allUserProvider.followUser(user.uid!);
                                  },

                                      child:
                                      Text(isFollowing ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow' ),
                                  ) : null


                          );

                        });
                  })`
```

I am trying to change button from follow to unfollow if user click on it and follow some one same for unfollow to convert back to follow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `stateful widget` and call `setState`

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users_info')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    final List<UserData> allUsers =
                        snapshot.data!.docs
                    .map((doc) => UserData.fromSnapshot(
                          doc.data(),
                          doc.id
                        )).toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: allUsers.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          UserData user = allUsers[index];
                          bool isCurrentUser = user.uid == allUserProvider.currentUser?.uid;
                         final bool isFollowing =
                         allUserProvider.currentUser?.following?.contains(user.uid ?? '') ?? false;
                        if(user.uid == currentUserId){
                          return Container();
                        }
                          return  ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(user.image ?? ''),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                user.name ?? '',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: GlobalVariables.fontsPally,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                user.uid ?? 'no id',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFFC1C0C9),
                                  fontFamily: GlobalVariables.fontsSatoshi,
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: !isCurrentUser ?
                                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
setState(){}
                                    print('${userId} and ${user.uid}');
                                 allUserProvider.followUser(user.uid!);
                                  },

                                      child:
                                      Text(isFollowing ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow' ),
                                  ) : null


                          );

                        });
                  })`
```

if the style of button isn't changed then the value of `isFollowing` is not changing.

you can check the following example.

```
class _PracticeState extends State<Practice> {
  bool isFollowing = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => isFollowing = !isFollowing),
        child: Text(isFollowing ? 'follow' : 'unfollow'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried it like that setState(() {
                                         allUserProvider.followUser(user.uid!);
                                     }); but still same issue

Comment: print the value of `isFollowing` to see if it's value is changing or not

Comment: It prints true but let me show you I am passing user is to isFollowing like that   bool isFollowing =
                             allUserProvider.currentUser?.following?.contains(user.uid ?? '') ?? false;

Comment: when i print the value it always print true

Comment: then there is a problem with `IsFollowing` not with your `button`

Comment: in firebase everything is working fine

Comment: ````   isFollowing =
                         allUserProvider.currentUser?.following?.contains(user.uid ?? '') ?? false;``` returns false only if `allUserProvider.currentUser` returns null. so i guess you have to change this function

Comment: it should be `isFollowing = allUserProvider.currentUser?.following?.contains(user.uid??'')==true?true:false;`